# Transform inner object as property of the outher object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object like this in my NodeJS backend:

```
{
    "x": "2021",
    "y": {
        "Kumada, K": 2,
        "Wu, XY": 4,
        "da Silva, BJP": 2
    }
}
```

And i would need it to become like this:

```
{
    "x": "2021",
    "Kumada, K": 2
    "Wu, XY": 4,
    "da Silva, BJP": 2    
}
```

EDIT: The "y" is dynamic which means it can have any number of different names, for example:

```
{
    "x": "2021",
    "y": {
        "Josh, K": 2,
        "Bob": 4,
        "Joseph": 2,
        "John": 0
    }
}
```

Any tips? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods) methods (both static and on prototype).

Comment: Do you know what keys it will have always? What is the structure of your incoming object.

Comment: @TusharShahi they keys inside the Y object will be dynamic, can have multiple different properties in there. I'll update the question for better undestanding, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below approach first creates an object based on `a.y` and then add all properties from `a` one by one using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Then it removes the `y` key, since it is not required.

```
let a = {
   "w" : "Hello",
    "x": "2021",
    "y": {
        "Kumada, K": 2,
        "Wu, XY": 4,
        "da Silva, BJP": 2
    }
}

let b = a.y;
Object.keys(a).forEach((x)=>{
  b[x] = a[x];
})
delete b.y
```

**This will be a [shallow copy](https://medium.com/@manjuladube/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c)**

For eg : If you have `a["x"]` as `{ 'prop1' : 22, 'prop2' : 33 }`. And you modify `a["x"]["prop1"] = 22`; This will be reflected in your final object too.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i needed, didnt know about Object.keys thats the part it was missing. I'm really sorry if my question was really noob or bad as people are downvoting it :(.

Comment: Tip : always show whatever you have tried. No matter how small or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Get to know [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax. It's magic sauce for this kind of thing

```js
let o = {
    "x": "2021", "y": { "Kumada, K": 2, "Wu, XY": 4, "da Silva, BJP": 2 }
    }
let newobj = { ...o, ...o.y };
delete newobj.y;
console.log(newobj)
```

Comment: Thats a great solution aswell, no need for a forEach loop in it! Thank you very much for your help aswel!